# I need to get an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to get an array of objects
The result must be like this, for example:

```
expenses = [ {fruits: 34, 
veget: 56, month: 1
}
{fruits: 59, 
veget: 23, month: 2
}
{fruits: 45, 
veget: 73, month: 3
}
...]
```

Comment: Welcome.  Show us what you tried.  If expenses is the output, what is the input?  Are selecting objects, or generating values?  Please clarify question, don't worry about answering my comment.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. Do you mean you need a collection of a given number of objects, each with the properties you show, each property having a random integer value [between a range]? If so, what's the specific problem? If not, what's the specific problem?

Comment: Yes I need to generate the values. I just created an example to show how it must look in console. But how to make it work have no idea

Comment: What's the *specific* problem? Generating a random integer in a range? Creating an object? Creating multiple objects?

Comment: the problem is to generate a random number  in an array of objects and to push it to console

Comment: Understood. Which particular part of that is causing a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var expenses  = [];
var months  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

for (var index = 1; index <= months.length; index++) {
    var element = months[index];
    
    expenses.push({
      fruits: randomRange(1, 100), 
      veget: randomRange(1, 100),
      month: element
    });
}

function randomRange(min, max) {
   return Math.floor( (Math.random() * (max-min +1) ) + min );
}

console.log(expenses);
```

As I guess you need this. Here we generate array items by months, which have random fruits and veget items with random values between 1-100. You can modify numbers as you need.